# Function calling w/ parameters

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I am struggling with creating functions and calling them in assembly.

The function `gfx_draw_h(color, x_1, y_1, x_2)` should be drawing a line from `(x_1, y_1)` to `(x_2, y_1)`, but I can't get the value of `x_2` to compare with the current position inside `gfx_draw_h.repeat`.

Also, is the other piece of code correct (no stack corruptions)?

This is my code:

```
    BITS 16

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------

_start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288
    mov ss, ax              ; SS = stack space
    mov sp, 4096            ; SP = stack pointer

    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax              ; DS = data segment

    call gfx_init

    push 50                 ; x_2
    push 30                 ; y_1
    push 30                 ; x_1
    push 1000b              ; color

    call gfx_draw_h

    add esp, 16

    jmp $                   ; infinite loop

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Initializes graphics.
;
; Sets the video mode.
;
; INPUT:
;   none
;
; OUTPUT:
;   none
;
gfx_init:
    mov ah, 00h             ; set video mode
    mov al, 12h             ; AL = graphical mode
    int 10h                 ; INT 10h / AH = 00h
    ret

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Draws a horizontal line.
;
; INPUT:
;   color
;   x_1
;   y_1
;   x_2
;
; OUTPUT:
;   none
;
gfx_draw_h:
    pop ax                  ; color
    pop cx                  ; x
    pop dx                  ; y

    mov ah, 0Ch             ; change color for a single pixel

.repeat:
    cmp cx, [ebp + 20]      ; !!! THIS IS THE ISSUE !!!
    je  .done

    inc cx
    int 10h

    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ; padding with 0 at the end
dw 0xAA55                   ; PC boot signature
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add esp, 16
```

Since this is 16-bit code pushing 4 parameters on the stack would only require you to pop off 8 bytes.

```
gfx_draw_h:
 pop ax                  ; color
 pop cx                  ; x
 pop dx                  ; y
```

Since *gfx_draw_h* is a sub-routine (it was `call`ed) there is a return address on the stack. Your first `pop ax` removes this! You could write the following:

```
gfx_draw_h:
 mov bp, sp
 mov ax, [bp+2] ;color
 mov cx, [bp+4] ;x
 mov dx, [bp+6] ;y
```

Following this logic change the problem line like (don't use EBP !):

```
cmp cx, [bp + 8]      ; !!! THIS IS THE ISSUE !!!
```

Comment: You forgot to `push bp` before overwriting it with `sp`.  Modern debuggers don't need a stack-frame at all, so you could just skip that part, esp. for leaf functions where you aren't modifying `sp`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did not really forget about `push bp` but was trying to keep it as simple as possible. And since the OP didn't care to push any registers...

Comment: @user3144770 Thank you! I understand what I was doing wrong before.
@PeterCordes What is the reason I should `push bp`? I added `push bp` right before `mov bp, sp` and `pop bp` right before `ret`. Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: @user5406450: yes.  If you don't save `bp`, you clobber the caller's stack frame.  `bp` is a callee-saved register in all ABIs: when a function returns, `rbp` / `ebp` / `bp` must have the value it did when the caller made the call.  Using `bp` this way is called a "stack frame".  As I said, it's optional.  modern gcc defaults to `-fomit-frame-pointer`, freeing up `rbp` for use as another general-purpose register.  In functions with variable-length arrays on the stack (`int foo[n];`), gcc will still make a stack frame to reference local variables from.  Google stack frame.

Comment: In this case, where you're only calling that function from code that doesn't use bp for a stack frame at the top level, you *could* clobber the caller's value.  But you could also just not make a stack frame in the function at all, and reference the function args relative to `sp`.  `mov ax, [sp+2]`.

Comment: I'm afraid that the 16-bit register `[sp]` is not a valid effective address. We HAD to use a stack frame in 16-bit  code!